# Power series expansion theorem for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the Power series expansion theorem for holomorphic functions? I need this for study so any help would be great.

Comment: Do you mean the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)?

Comment: a previous exam question was " state the power series expansion theorem for holomorphic functions and give an integral formula for the coefficients of the power series" @eyeballfrog so maybe the second part is referring to that?

Comment: @eyeballfrog to tag since I forgot